# Add value to App-Info.plist after deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

Is there a way to add (or update) a value to my App's info.plist dynamically (eg from data from a server)?

For example adding or changing the FacebookAppID and the corresponding facebook url scheme dynamically while an app is live.

Comment: Oops, this slipped from my search... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Info.plist is part of your app bundle, which is read only.

But even if you could, not a good idea.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Flexicoder They were asking if they could edit the info.plist while the app is running. I gave an answer of it being read only, which is another valid way of saying "No". They didn't ask for anything else.